# Scan unknown number of inputs and print bar chart in C

Tags: c

I am at a loss.  Attached a picture of the problem that I've been working on for at least 6 hours and can't figure out.
To summarize what the problem is asking--read an input of integers off one line only.  The first number in the line specifies how many numbers will follow(anywhere from 1 to 40 numbers).  Then use the following numbers and create bar charts at the very bottom with "*" corresponding to the numbers entered.  Like I said, read the attached picture, it'll make more sense.
I can get the program to work but only if I have the user input the numbers on separate lines.  Also I know how to do it using an array. However we are NOT allowed to use arrays. Can only use for loops, any variation of while loops, nested loops, if statements, pow function, int float and double, switch statement, getchar(), scanf(), and logical operators.  I posted my code but its useless.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: picture of problem]

```
//Homework 4 - Question 3

//main.c


//indicates preprocessor
#include <stdio.h>


//being function main
int main(void){


    //define variables
    int barnum, counter = 1, counter2 = 0, length = 0;


    //prompt for number of bars user wants to input
    printf("--------------------Bar Chart Calculator--------------------\n");
    printf("Enter integers from 1 to 40 for questions below.\n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("Enter the number of bars wanted in chart: ");
    scanf("%d", &barnum);

    printf("Enter the length of each bar, pressing enter after each entry.\n");
    printf("---------Begin entering integers below this line-------------\n");



    //while loop to repeat for specified number of bars
    while (counter <= barnum){
        length = 0;
        counter2 = 0;
        scanf("%d", &length);

        //while loop to print individual * in a single line
        while (counter2 < length) {
            printf("*");
            counter2++;  //increments counter
        }//end counter 2 while loop

        printf("(%d)\n", length);
        counter++;  //increments counter

    }  //end counter while loop


    return 0;  //indicates program ended successfully

}  //end function main
```

Comment: So you are asking about your code, which can only read user input when it is one number per line. Certainly seeing your code is not useless in helping you fix it! Or, if you are asking someone else to write the code for you, then SO is not the right site to ask for services like that.

Comment: posted it. below the question. but like i said i read all the numbers on separate lines which isn't how its supposed to be done so I was worried it would confuse people reading the question.  thanks for the suggestion on posting my code though, im new here

Comment: What is your problem? Your code looks to me like it can handle input on one line? Can it not? What happens if you try? Can you simplify your question by asking about reading numbers from a single line(leaving out all the other unrelated stuff)?

Comment: My main problem is reading an unknown number of integers off of a single line and being able to use them later.  Without using an array or making 40 different variables.  In regards to my code i think because of the scanf's that makes it impossible to read multiple numbers in a line without conversion specifiers for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `stdin` input stream is typically buffered in C, so whatever input is in the stream after the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> will be available to `scanf()` until that input is exhausted. After the first call to `scanf()`, you will have the number of input items to follow. Then a loop can execute further calls to `scanf()` until there is no more input to read.

Note that more robust code should check the value returned by the call to `scanf()` to guard against malformed input and rare input failure events.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num_values;
    scanf("%d", &num_values);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++) {
        int val;
        scanf("%d", &val);
        printf("Value %d: %d\n", i, val);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample program interaction:

```
>$ ./a.out 
6 3 1 4 1 5 9
Value 0: 3
Value 1: 1
Value 2: 4
Value 3: 1
Value 4: 5
Value 5: 9
```

### Potential Pitfalls

Since input remains in the input stream until it is read by some function call, subsequent calls to `scanf()` may pick up previous, unread, input values, leading to unexpected (and possibly undefined) behavior.

For example, if the bar chart program loops to allow the user to enter another data set after displaying the results for the first one, it is possible for problems to arise. Suppose the user has entered more data than indicated by the first number: `3 1 2 3 4`. After the bar graphs have been displayed, the `4` will still remain in the input stream. A subsequent call to `scanf()` would pick up this `4`, instead of whatever input the code is expecting. Try commenting out the call to `clear_stream()` in the code below and see what happens when the input line contains more items than expected.

The idiomatic solution is to clear the input stream by reading all remaining characters in the input stream using `getchar()`:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    continue;
}
```

The variable `c` needs to be an `int` rather than a `char` to ensure that the value returned by `getchar()` (which is an `int` and may be `EOF`, typically `-1`) can be held in `c`. The loop reads and discards the characters in the input stream until a newline or `EOF` is reached. The `getchar()` function returns `EOF` in the rare event of an error, but a user may also enter `EOF`, so this value must be explicitly tested for to avoid a possible infinite loop.

To avoid further problems with malformed input, check the value returned by the call to `scanf()`. This function returns the number of successful assignments made during the call as an `int` value (or may return `EOF`). If the user has entered a letter instead of a number for the initial value indicating the number of values in the dataset, no value is stored in `num_values` (and so the value of `num_values` remains indeterminate). This leads to undefined behavior when the code later attempts to use `num_values`. By checking to see whether `scanf()` has returned a value of `1` as expected, this situation can be avoided.

The code below allows the user to enter a line of data, preceded by the number of data items. If the user enters `-1` (or any value less than 1, or non-numeric input) for the number of items, the program exits. Also, if the user has entered non-numeric input within the data items, a graph for that input item is simply not displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clear_stream(void);
void print_bar(int n);

int main(void)
{
    char *prompt = "Enter the number of values to graph, followed by the values"
                   " (-1 to exit)";
    int num_values;
    puts(prompt);
    int ret_scanf = scanf("%d", &num_values);

    while (ret_scanf == 1 && num_values > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_values; i++) {
            int val;
            /* print bar if a number was entered */
            if (scanf("%d", &val) == 1) {
                print_bar(val);
            }
        }
        putchar('\n');
        puts(prompt);
        clear_stream();                        // try commenting out this line
        ret_scanf = scanf("%d", &num_values);
    }

    return 0;
}

void clear_stream(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        continue;
    }
}

void print_bar(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        putchar('*');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Sample program interaction:

```
>$ ./a.out 
Enter the number of values to graph, followed by the values (-1 to exit)
6 3 1 4 1 5 9
***
*
****
*
*****
*********

Enter the number of values to graph, followed by the values (-1 to exit)
-1
```

Comment: That's exactly what I couldn't figure out.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @DavidJones -- I have updated my answer to include some discussion about potential problems due to the persistence of input in the input stream, and due to malformed input.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks bud.  After your first post i got it figured out, i just didn't know you could scan the same line multiple times but your example was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. You don't need to create 41 variables. You can enter as many values as you want but if the `scanf` statement takes in only one value it will take the first value and the rest of the values will stay in queue. So the next time the control encounters a `scanf` statement it takes in the second value that you entered before.

In your question, you have to first enter the number of values that follow. You can use this to learn how many times you have run the scanf statement in a loop. I have used here a combination of `if` statement and `goto`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int i, j, k, l=1;

/* Here variable 'i' stores the first number entered */

printf("Enter intergers from 1 to 40 where first number indicates how many 
numbers follow: ");
scanf("%d", &i);



a : scanf("%d", &j);

for(k=1 ; k<=j; k++)
{
    printf("*");
}

printf("\n");
l++;
if(l<=i)
goto a;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks big homie! ya i didn't know the scanf could be used multiple times to scan the same line